# Rewrite images In Sub Directory

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been looking over many examples but just can't get my head around this, may be it isn't possible. I've inherited a mess of a Wordpress site.

I have this DIR structure, Wordpress:

```
/wp-content/uploads/
/wp-content/uploads/2011
/wp-content/uploads/2012
/wp-content/uploads/Organised
/wp-content/uploads/Organised/0-9
/wp-content/uploads/Organised/A
/wp-content/uploads/Organised/B
/wp-content/uploads/Organised/ and so on ... to Z
```

Basically there were over 93,000 files in the `/wp-content/uploads/` folder, and some in the 2011, and 2012 folders. I need to move the 93,000 files so decided to make the "Organised" folder with folders in there reflecting the first letter/number of potential files.

While this isn't an issue, with moving them that is, I need to make sure external requests can still access those files based on the old URL.

So:

```
/wp-content/uploads/APicture.jpg
```

Will Rewrite to:

```
/wp-content/uploads/Organised/A/APicture.jpg
```

While still allowing access to actual URLS like:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2012/AnotherPicture.jpg
```

I thought a Rewrite URL like this would work but it doesn't and I have tried many variations, maybe it just can't work like this?

```
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/([^/]+)(\.png|\.jpg|\.bmp|\.gif)$ /wp-content/Organised/T/$1$2
```

**Note:** For testing I was checking a URL `/wp-content/uploads/taylor-swift-harry-styles.jpg` such is why I hardcoded the resulting rewrite URL but I realise it needs to be changes to match the initial letter.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/Organised   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/(\w)([^/]+)\.(png|jpg|bmp|gif)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*   wp-content/Organised/%1/%1%2.%3    [L]
```

It will redirect URLs like this one:

`http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/Taylor-swift-harry-styles.jpg`

But not like this one:

`http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/Taylor-swift-harry-styles.jpg`

To:

`http://example.com/wp-content/Organised/T/Taylor-swift-harry-styles.jpg`

Where directory `T` is the first character of the file name. It can be a single digit or a single letter.

It will keep the letter case, though. For example, if the letter is in lower case, the mapped directory will be `t` and **must exist**. Same happens when the letter is in upper case.

Comment: Thanks faa, so far so good. Though I didn't think about the uppercase/lowercase issue. SO does this means I will need to make both an "a" and "A" directory, and so on to z/Z, and sort the files accordingly? I guess this would make sense as it is on a Linux box but what if it was to move to Windows, case doesn't matter - would it be a problem then?

Comment: I don't think so, although it would be better an safer to have a single policy on that matter: The one that complies with Linux and HTTP, I guess.

Comment: Ok I modified it slightly. The first works fine, it catches a-z, A-Z and 0-9 chars. The second is meant to catch everything else, symbols, but it doesn't fire. What am I doing wrong. FIRST: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/([A-Za-z0-9])([^/]+)\.([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* wp-content/uploads/_Organised/%1/%1%2.%3 [L] SECOND: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/(.*)$/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* wp-content/uploads/_Organised/_Misc/%1 [L]

Comment: Nevermind the comment, I posted the code for readability as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per Faa's comment I modified my code and put it here for readability.

```
#   !!!
#   !!! Requires directories to be present: a-z; A-Z; 0-9
#   !!!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/uploads/_Organised   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/([A-Za-z0-9])([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* wp-content/uploads/_Organised/%1/%1%2.%3 [L]

#   !!!
#   !!! Matches "Other" characters/files that were not caught above
#   !!!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/uploads/_Organised   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/(.*)$/? [NC]
RewriteRule .* wp-content/uploads/_Organised/_Misc/%1 [L]
```

I think it works, it seems to be but am I coorect with the Regex? I need to make sure that ONLY files at the `/wp-content/uploads/` are matched and none deeper.

That's why I put the -f and -d flags, is this over kill? Until I put those in there was a problem with the second Rule where it would catch files in sub directories. Also is the ($) sign warranted here?

Comment: This `([A-Za-z0-9])` is this `[\w]` plus underscore `_` in my answer, so ¿why the modification? On the other hand, you add 2 `REQUEST_FILENAME` conditions that are not necessary as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/Organised   [NC]` is already preventing any loop, so, again, ¿why the modification to my answer and why it is not working for you? The `"Other" characters/files...` were not in your question and that's why they are not in my answer either.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand Regex and I haven't been able to find a resource that explains all the possible inputs, [\w] for example. I couldn't find what it meant. I'll remove the extra RewriteConds.

Comment: `\w` is any valid word character plus underscore `_`, including digits.